# Find out specific amount of latest versions of npm module

Tags: command-line, npm, version

Is there any way how to view specific amount of latest versions of npm module in command line?

E.g. `npm view webpack 5 latest versions`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a build-in npm command to do that, however, utilizing both [npm-view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) and [npm-ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) can achieve something similar to what I think you're asking for.

---

**bash**

The following should work in most bash shells. It will print a tree showing all installed instances of the latest version of a particular package/module:

For a local project `cd` to its directory and run:

`V=$(npm show webpack version) && npm ls webpack@$V`

The command above does the following:

1. The result from running `npm show webpack version`, (which by itself performs a lookup to the npm repository and returns the latest/current version number), is assigned to a variable named `V`.
2. Next the `npm ls webpack@` command is run and the value of variable `V` is assigned so that only instances of the latest package version are listed.

For listing the latest version of globally installed packages add the `-g` argument/flag. E.g.

`V=$(npm show webpack version) && npm ls webpack@$V -g`

---

**cmd.exe**

The following two commands will achieve a similar result in Windows using cmd:

For a local project `cd` to its directory and run:

`for /f %i in ('npm show webpack version') do set V=%i`

`npm ls webpack@%V%`

For listing the latest version of globally installed packages, again add the `-g` argument/flag. E.g.

`npm ls webpack@%V%` -g